# Main differences between Politics.SE and Quora?

Tags: discussion, scope, user-interface

[*User4012* opines](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/27930/is-there-a-country-that-leans-far-to-the-right?noredirect=1#comment103542_27930):

> Quora is... ... not exactly a reliable source of information.

Is Politics.SE objectively better than [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) in any obvious, major, and uncontroversial respects, and if so, which respects would those be?

Comment: This is not as objective as you wish, but basically Politics.SE *can sometimes* be bubble echo chamber, but that's not majority of cases (especially if you filter out HNQ posts). Quora seems to be that nearly 100% of time.

Comment: @user4012, Your comment might make a good answer, if it explained more about in what way Quora is like an echo chamber, (*i.e.* one-sided, spammy, tyrannically edited, buggy, or some other problem), ...

Answer (score 3):

You set the hurdle quite high. Objectively better in any obvious, major and  uncontroversial respect is almost surely impossible because better is mostly subjective and quite often controversial. It probably strongly depends on your perspective.

Therefore I would say that the answer to your question is a clear: No, there aren't any obvious, major and uncontroversial aspects in which Politics.SE is objectively better than Quora.

Having said that, there are of course differences between Quora and StackExchange. Both focus on Expert Q&A, but they are not the same and do it in somewhat different ways. These different approaches may have an impact on the resulting quality of the content.

I don't see what makes Politics.SE special among all the SEs, so a general reference to a Quora vs. StackExchange discussion should already give a lot of insight. Google Quora vs. StackExchange to learn more. Out of the top of my head I would say that Quora demands you to register and doesn't have the voting system of the SEs. But whether this makes Quora better or worse, I don't know really.

Comment: This question made me curious, need to lookup the content license of Quora and see if it is also an open license.

Comment: I checked the [Quora content license](https://www.quora.com/about/tos) and it is much less open than the StackExchange content license. You may only reproduce the content but not alter it and instead of citing the author, you have to cite Quora and you have to keep the copy updated and delete once the content is deleted from Quora. I would regard that as making Quora worse than StackExchange at least to me.

Comment: That Quora license does sound objectively worse.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the license issue discussed in the comments, Quora has an annoying rule that you can't see more than one question without signing in.